# jQuery.ajax doesn't send proper ajax headers when using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, https

Whenever I create an `jQuery.ajax` request it works fine when the URL uses the HTTP protocol. But when I send the same request to the HTTPs server, it is sent without the header [`HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest`]. Thus the server has no way of knowing that this is an AJAX request!

I've tried:

- Switching $.ajax, $.post, $.get
- Forcing the header using `beforeSend`
- Setting `CrossDomain:true`

*Note: There are no cross-domain issues, the request is valid and handled, but not as AJAX.*

This issue happens when the current URL is http but the requested URL is on the same domain but uses HTTPS.
http://example.com/home
will use AJAX POST to post to

Comment: This **is** a cross-domain issue AFAIK. [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) requires requests to be on the same protocol and port (where-as you're using HTTP -> HTTPS and 80 -> 443). It would seem (without any more info), that jQuery *is* making a JSONP request behind the scenes, which ignores additional HTTP headers.

Comment: You mean when you are on the HTTP server and make an ajax request to the HTTPS server right?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for the right header? Which jquery version are you on? Every time I've had to do this, jquery has set the x-requested-with header, not the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header.

Comment: Neither of them are set!
I'm on jQuery v1.7.1

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier yest, this is the case.

Comment: Then I would lean towards Matt's comment and digg some more in that direction...

Comment: Would jQuery silently fallback to jsonp? I'm setting the returned data type explicitly as 'script'.

Comment: @mjalajel No, in this case it would not fallback to `jsonp`, however it would be sent as a `GET` request using `<script>` tags. When using `<script>` tags to make the request, it is not possible to set headers.

Comment: Do you just need the request type so you can set the response mime type on the server?

Comment: If the thing you're fetching is a `<script>`, then why would you need to differentiate between AJAX requests and traditional requests?

Comment: I'm on jQuery 1.8.2 and had to set the header by hand. I found that setting it as HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH didn't work though, I had to call setRequestHeader with "X-Requested-With". I've posted example code in a separate answer. I spotted this having become concerned by @Matt's suggestion that SOP required ports to match, so I cracked open the jQuery code. I didn't find any evidence to support that, but did notice the format for setting headers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue for doing same stuff between http and https.
I have researched this and it is cross domain issue. Please try JSONP with call back function for doing the stuff, and the most important thing the server side page you are using for doing curl has to set some headers for allowing http to https connection. These are below:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your https url");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Connection, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
header("Connection: close");
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to your formatting, don't format your whole post as code block..

Answer (score 5):

I tried Kishor's approach, but the header didn't get sent. I modified it, setting the header like this:

```
$.ajax {
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  },
  ...
};
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax {
    ...
    ...
    beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
                   jqXHR.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XmlHttpRequest"
                 }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Hope this one helps :D